# Blender starting up slow

Tags: startup-file

Blender used to start up fast to me on the default start up file
Now it starts up and it takes about 30 seconds to a minute. My computer is fast and relatively new. Is there anything I should do to cut down this start up time?

Edit: if you’re wondering what version I’m on I’m on 3.6.4.
And no my computer cannot run beyond 4.0 because of some driver issue I cannot fix

Comment: Try turning off any external addons you have loaded one at a time until the startup speed improves.